# Create an obseravable that watches for a class array variable change

Tags: angular, typescript

Still getting my head around observables and I'm trying to do something I'm pretty sure is possible.

Our application has a class variable called references, which is an array of type FormArray.

```
references = new FormArray([]);
```

This particular form is fairly standard CRUD, where the references array is populated from a service with an array of objects, and the forms are patched with the return values.

I'm working on a story where I have to get the reference that was created first, and then bubble that value up to a parent component.  And I have it working, using an event emitter.  On each CRUD function, I pass the references to a method that sorts them and then finds the oldest one.

```
setOldest(references: FormArray): void {
    const firstBolRef = filtered.reduce((a, b) => new Date(a.value.Created) < new Date(b.value.Created) ? a : b);
    this.firstBOLChanged.emit(firstBolRef.value);
  }
```

I feel like there's a way to set up an observable that watches the references array and then outputs the value instead of calling the setOldest function on every event.  I haven't found an example that's doing quite what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually subscribe to the changes of a form field (or to the whole form).
I don't know it is going to work just for an FormArray control (that is not inside a form), but you can try this:

Once you have inicialized references with *references = new FormArray([]);*
do this:

```
this.references.valueChanges.pipe(tap((values) => {console.log(values);}));
```

If you get by console a value everytime that this.references changes, you only have to change the console.log() instruction by the code you want.

Comment: I had to go a different direction altogether on this but thanks for the reply